# Reinitialize vector values

Tags: c++

I have class Enemy:

```
class Enemy
{
   Enemy();
   Enemy(string n, int u, int v, int p, int vy);
   ~Enemy();
}
```

I have class Game, where I have method called fight();

```
class Game
{
  public:
  Game();
  ~Game();
  void Fight();
  private:
  vector<Enemy> e;

}
void Game::Fight()
{
   e.push_back(Enemy("Skeleton",1,2,3,4));
   //code for displaying info about Enemy
   //code for reducing hp
}
```

I need to reinitialize values of Enemy in every fight call.

Comment: "isn't working" is too vague. voting to close.

Comment: The vector element has a copy of e performed prior to the e.clear().  So, the e you created and cleared is different than the e you push_back()'ed.

Comment: idk why people wants me to create another account and ask same question again instead of answer me..

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN ok then and how to fix it?

Comment: To improve your question, you should show enough of your code to a) show what you did, and b) describe or show what the results were, and c) describe what you expected.  Without the code, how can we help?  What you have given so far does not compile, does not run, so we can not re-create your code.

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN edited

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "reinitialize values"?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik when I call that fight metod again I want have Skeleton with full hp not 0..

Comment: If you don't want to preserve state between calls, then why make `e` a member variable in the first place? Just make it a local variable in `Fight`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I will need it for another methods too..

Comment: Make it `e.clear(); e.push_back(...);`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik don't understand that.. I tried to call e.clear() at the end of fight and when it was called again it didn't reset the values..

Comment: Reinitialize with what exactly?

Comment: a) I suggest you call it at the beginning of `Fight`, right before `push_back`. b) What do you mean by "didn't reset the values"? Are you suggesting that, after `e.clear()` call, `e.size()` is not zero? With all due respect, I find this difficult to believe.

Comment: Why are you using a vector if you only want to put one thing in it?

Comment: You should only submit code that compiles, is minimal, and reproduces the problem of your posting.  See [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much to go on, but here's a few hints.

1. You could make the `std::vector` local to `Game::Fight()`:

   ```
   void Game::Fight()
   {
       std::vector<Enemy> e = { {"Skeleton",1,2,3,4} };
       //...
   }
   ```
2. You could leave it as a member object and clear it before you put enemies in it:

   ```
   void Game::Fight()
   {
       e.clear();
       e.push_back({"Skeleton",1,2,3,4});
       //...
   }
   ```
3. You could just reassign it, which is basically the same thing as above:

   ```
   void Game::Fight()
   {
       e = { {"Skeleton",1,2,3,4} };
       //...
   }
   ```
4. You could modify the current enemy that's in there, but you'd have to actually *add* the enemy somewhere first, maybe in the constructor:

   ```
   void Game::Fight()
   {
       e[0].hp = 100;
       //...
   }
   ```
5. You could *ask the enemy to reset itself* by adding `Enemy::reset()`. This function would reset the hp, mp, etc.:

   ```
   void Game::Fight()
   {
       e[0].reset();
       // ...
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Your code (of your current posting) does not compile.  Missing includes, missing semicolons, and several other things.  You should only submit code that compiles and reproduces the problem you are trying to understand.

And there is still too little info about your effort for me to guess where you are heading.  My imagination is generally the first thing to fail me.  My mind reading ability is also quite slow to catch on.

But I have experience with vectors and some debug style outputs (which you 
will want to comment out when they make too much noise).

---

Here is something to contemplate that mimics this early code.  Though it compiles and "runs", I think it does not answers any specific question of yours.  But perhaps it shows that you need to consider what you want in your vector.  "Copies", for instance, cause both ctors and dtors to be invoked, which can impact performance if your games creates more during gaming action, but probably ok during start-up and shut-down.

```
  class Enemy
  {
     static int M_id;

     int m_id;
     std::string m_s;

  public:
     Enemy() : m_id(++M_id)
        {
           std::cout << "ctor Enemy() [empty]" << m_id << std::endl;
        };

     Enemy(std::string n, int u, int v, int p, int vy) :
        m_id(++M_id) // default m_s ok
        {
           std::stringstream ss;
           ss << "ctor Enemy: " << m_id << "  " << n
              << " " << u << " " << v << " " << p << " " << vy;
           m_s = ss.str();
        };

     ~Enemy()
        {
           std::cout << "dtor ~Enemy() " << std::endl;
        };

     std::string show()
        {
           std::string s ("Enemy show() E: ");
           s += m_s;
           return (s);
        }

  };

  int Enemy::M_id = 0;

  class Game
  {
  public:
     Game() // default ctor e is ok
        {
           e.reserve(100);
           std::cout << "\n\nctor Game()" << std::endl;
        };

     ~Game()
        {
           std::cout << "dtor !Game()" << std::endl;
        };

     void Fight(int p4)
        {
           e.push_back(Enemy("Skeleton",1,2,3,p4));
           //code for displaying info about Enemy
           //code for reducing hp
        }

     std::string show()
        {
           std::stringstream ss;
           ss << "    Game.show()  e.size() = " << e.size() << "\n";
           for (auto el : e)
           {
              ss << el.show() << "\n";
           }

           return (ss.str());
        }


  private:
     std::vector<Enemy> e;
  };


  int t423(void)
  {
     {
        Game g1;
        std::cout << "\ng1.show(): " << g1.show() << std::endl;

        g1.Fight(11);
        std::cout << "\ng1.show(): " << g1.show() << std::endl;

        g1.Fight(12);
        std::cout << "\ng1.show(): " << g1.show() << std::endl;

        g1.Fight(13);
        std::cout << "\ng1.show(): " << g1.show() << std::endl;

        std::cout << "\n --- leaving scope (of g1) " << std::endl;
     }

     std::cout << "\n ---  triggers g1 and vector dtors (which triggers Enemy dtors)" << std::endl;

     return(0);
  }
```